# Можно ли отмониторить последние изменения в коде в IntellijIdea без гита?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

У меня есть проект (очень большой) в `IntellijIdea` где я экспериментирую. Там много директорий, в каждой директории много классов. А я уже забыл куда вчера вносил изменения. Можно ли как-нибудь найти последние десять файлов которые я правил? Или только после подключения к системе контроля версий можно это найти?

Comment: Выполнить поиск файлов по маске *, отсортировать результаты по дате изменения.

Comment: @Kromster в тотал командере?

Comment: @Kromster видите ↓ как бывает, задницей чуял что есть встроенный функционал.

Comment: В любом файловом менеджере, включая стандартные Виндовые окошки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правой кнопкой на дереве файлов → Local history → Show history

Comment: Откуда вы всё это знаете? Наверное в Idea на java разрабатываете.

Comment: Конкретно IDEA я знаю не очень хорошо, просто уже видел подобный вопрос.

Comment: я искал, не нашёл аналог. Плохо искал наверное.

Comment: Вашу жеж материнскую плату! Аж до августа, начальство отмониторить может активность. Опасно!